# How to generate key on git bash

Tags: windows, git, homestead

I use this command on git bash

```
`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "eu.json@gmail.com"`
```

After that, these line of text show.

```
`'Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/jayson/.ssh/id_rsa):'.`
```

There is no other line of text shown and stuck there, I wait for long time and still nothing happen not like the video that i follow, I need to use it on laravel homestead.

Comment: "Enter file in which to save the key", well obviously it's asking you to enter a filename (or just use the default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to click <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (twice if you don't want a passphrase associated to the private key).

That will validate the file to be saved.

- `/c/Users/jayson/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key)
- `/c/Users/jayson/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key)

If you don't want to be "stuck there", you can also type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "eu.json@gmail.com" -P ""
                                         ^^^^^
```

That would generate a key pair without passphrase (the private key won't be encrypted).

Comment: when i press enter these line of text shows
'Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):'
which i did not see on the video that i follow

Comment: i did not see 'Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):' on the video that i follow so im worried that i do something wrong, but i just go hit enter 2 times and its done thanks